# No ClearType in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: cleartype, internet-explorer-11, font-smoothing

### Problem

Internet Explorer 11 (on Windows 8.1) seems to ignore system font smoothing preferences. Even though ClearType is enabled on the system, IE11 keeps smoothing using gradients.

### Question

Is there any way to enable ClearType smoothing in IE11?

Comment: While I understand and agree that animation and smooth zooming are important on tablets, the desktop browser user experience should not be sacrificed. Although not a direct answer to your question, I switched to Chrome browser exactly for this reason. I spend a lot of time in browser, so I want the best for my eyes. Desktop IE10 or IE11 does not offer that anymore.

Comment: @TomasKarban: I'm using Chrome exclusively on a day-by-day basis but doing development leaves the inevitable trip to IE... :(

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Modern UI (Metro) apps does not support ClearType. And for desktop environment ClearType still works with one direction, so when you rotate the screen it won't change either

http://www.istartedsomething.com/20120303/cleartype-takes-a-back-seat-for-windows-8-metro/

Comment: I'm not running IE in fullscreen mode (as Modern UI app) but rather on the desktop in a normal window. And I'm running on a desktop computer without any rotation capabilities.

Comment: BTW: All other apps (including Windows 8 itself) render fonts using ClearType. It's just IE that *slapped me with a glove*.

Comment: Maybe that's the problem of DirectWrite. IE9 and above, MS Office 2013 and some newer MS applications changed to DirectWrite that makes text rendering sometimes worse

Comment: Office too? haven't got it on my machine, so I wouldn't know... That's actually very bad as they stepped back a decade or so.